# How to make FindBugs Security JSP work with WEB plugin in Sonar 5.6.3?

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

FindBugs Security JSP conflicts with WEB plugin when I configure it to scan for .jsp files by putting .html,.xhtml,.rhtml,.shtml,.jsp in the `File suffixes` option. When I run sonar:sonar on maven I got the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar
>   (default-cli) on project testeSonar: Language of file
>   'src/main/webapp/index.jsp' can not be decided as the file matches
>   patterns of both sonar.lang.patterns.jsp : **/*.jsp and
>   sonar.lang.patterns.web :
>   **/*.html,***/.xhtml,**/*.rhtml,***/.shtml,**/*.jsp -> [Help 1]

How can I put both to work properly? If that is not possible is there a way to disable FindBugs Security JSP profile so that WEB plugin can scan jsp files as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each file extension may be declared by one, and only one plugin (see https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-145). Your problem is that two plugins have declared the same extension. You should be able to edit the global settings (Administration > [language name]) to restrict the file extension to the plugin of your choice. Currently it is possible to disable the jsp file scan for the WEB plugin, but not the FindBugs Security JSP, as it does not provide this option in the administration tab (see https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-findbugs/issues/67)

Be aware that this means that this kind of configuration makes one of the plugins to ignore files with that extension.

Comment: jsp don't appear in the administration page, while it is in the Quality profile with a FindBugs Security JSP profile default.

Comment: I don't want to disable the jsp from the web plugin, I want to disable the FindBugs Security JSP.

Comment: I was thinking, it is a strong constraint this one of file extension. As plugins projects raises, they might consider to extend their scan to more file formats, and then people will have a hard choose between possibly two good plugins. It is really that way sonar works today?

Comment: How much more definitively can I say it?

Comment: "How much more definitively can I say it?": By providing a reference to an official documentation of SonarQube or to a ticket issue. Also, I cannot edit the global settings the way you described to make WEB plugin scan jsp files.